# What's the best way to store access token generated from third party API in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, google-ads-api, aws-secrets-manager

I'm currently running a script locally to generate reports using GoogleAdsManager API. Prior running the script I've created new service account key in json format as the key type together with `~/googleads.yaml`.

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/start) the dev guide.

However, I wanted to schedule this script on (`AWS Glue`).

This is the sample script and the issue I currently faced is :

How do call this method ad_manager.AdManagerClient.[LoadFromStorage()](https://googleads.github.io/googleads-python-lib/googleads.ad_manager.AdManagerClient-class.html) from aws? I've stored the credentials (`JSON` and `YAML`) in AWS Secrets Manager

```
from googleads import ad_manager, oauth2
import tempfile
import _locale

_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'UTF-8'])

ad_unit_id = XXXXXXXXXX

def generate_ad_impressions(client):
    # Initialize appropriate service.
    report_service = client.GetService("ReportService", 
    version="v202108")
    # Initialize a DataDownloader.
    report_downloader = client.GetDataDownloader(version="v202108")
    # Create statement object to filter for an order.
    statement = (
        ad_manager.StatementBuilder(version="v202108")
        .Where("PARENT_AD_UNIT_ID = :id")
        .WithBindVariable("id", mbns_aa_vod_ad_unit_id)
        .Limit(None)  # No limit/offset for reports
        .Offset(None)
    )
    report_job = {
        "reportQuery": {
        "dimensions": ["DATE", "HOUR"],
        "columns": [
            "AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS",
        ],
        "dateRangeType": "TODAY",
        "startDate": {
            "year": "2022",
            "month": "1",
            "day": "25"
        },
        "endDate": {
            "year": "2022",
            "month": "1",
            "day": "25"
        },
        "statement": statement.ToStatement(),
      }
    }
    try:
        # Run the report and wait for it to finish.
        report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)
    except:
        print("Failed to generate report.")
        # Change to your preferred export format.
        export_format = "CSV_DUMP"
        # report_file = 
        tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".csv.gz", 
        delete=False)
    with open('ad_unit_report.csv.gz', mode='wb') as report_file:
        # Download report data.
        report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(report_job_id, 
        export_format, report_file)
        report_file.close()

    # Download report data.
    downloaded_report = 
    report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(report_job_id, 
    export_format, report_file)

    report_file.close()
    print('success!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ad_manager_client = 
   ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage('path_to_yaml_file')
   generate_ad_impressions(ad_manager_client)
```

Comment: There are many options.. Have you considered [AWS system manager parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) ?

Comment: Hi, Currently im using the AWS Secrets Manager to store both files (JSON n YAML file). I tried to run the script using AWS Glue. Usually if it's running from my local i just called the class method 'LoadFromStorage' and provide the path to the YAML file. But in AWS Im not too sure how to provide the path to the yaml file. Attached are the available parameter provided by google ads https://googleads.github.io/googleads-python-lib/googleads.ad_manager.AdManagerClient-class.html

Comment: Google ad manager API also provides a method called `LoadFromString('yaml_string')`. Have you looked at using that instead of LoadFromStorage? Also you can get the string via the boto3 python library. Let me know if this worked for you or need sample.

Comment: Yes please provide sample. Thanks!~

Comment: Provided as a solution. Test it on your side and let us know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution should be something like this:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from googleads import ad_manager, oauth2
import tempfile
import _locale

_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'UTF-8'])

ad_unit_id = XXXXXXXXXX

def get_secret():
    secret_name = "MySecret"
    region_name = "us-west-2"

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            print("The request had invalid params:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailure':
            print("The requested secret can't be decrypted using the provided KMS key:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceError':
            print("An error occurred on service side:", e)
    else:
        # Secrets Manager decrypts the secret value using the associated KMS CMK
        # Depending on whether the secret was a string or binary, only one of these fields will be populated
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            text_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            return text_secret_data
        else:
            binary_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']
            return binary_secret_data

def generate_ad_impressions(client):
    # Initialize appropriate service.
    report_service = client.GetService("ReportService", 
    version="v202108")
    # Initialize a DataDownloader.
    report_downloader = client.GetDataDownloader(version="v202108")
    # Create statement object to filter for an order.
    statement = (
        ad_manager.StatementBuilder(version="v202108")
        .Where("PARENT_AD_UNIT_ID = :id")
        .WithBindVariable("id", mbns_aa_vod_ad_unit_id)
        .Limit(None)  # No limit/offset for reports
        .Offset(None)
    )
    report_job = {
        "reportQuery": {
        "dimensions": ["DATE", "HOUR"],
        "columns": [
            "AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS",
        ],
        "dateRangeType": "TODAY",
        "startDate": {
            "year": "2022",
            "month": "1",
            "day": "25"
        },
        "endDate": {
            "year": "2022",
            "month": "1",
            "day": "25"
        },
        "statement": statement.ToStatement(),
      }
    }
    try:
        # Run the report and wait for it to finish.
        report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)
    except:
        print("Failed to generate report.")
        # Change to your preferred export format.
        export_format = "CSV_DUMP"
        # report_file = 
        tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".csv.gz", 
        delete=False)
    with open('ad_unit_report.csv.gz', mode='wb') as report_file:
        # Download report data.
        report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(report_job_id, 
        export_format, report_file)
        report_file.close()

    # Download report data.
    downloaded_report = 
    report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(report_job_id, 
    export_format, report_file)

    report_file.close()
    print('success!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   ad_manager_client = 
   ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromString(get_secret())
   generate_ad_impressions(ad_manager_client)
```

Here the function `get_secret` fetches the YAML string from AWS Secrets Manager stored as **MySecret** in region us-west-2. The YAML string is then subsequently used to create the Google Ad Manager Client using the function `LoadFromString`.

Note that I have not tested this as I do not have Google API key and Id.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the input. It is useful but I got an error message after i ran the script. The error logs are as follow:

```data = self.stream.read(size)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? Want to know the error is from which line number.

Comment: I decided to go with parameter store like the suggested solution given above. But in the yaml file we need to provide full path to the private key file. For testing purpose i stored the file in my s3 and provide the path. But in the error logs it says the file does not exist. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Did you check IAM policy?

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks!